# How to output a variable on a MySQL query string?

Tags: php, mysql

I just tried everything I could, but nothing works. I think the code is self-explanatory:

```
$username = "stringvalue1";
$password = "stringvalue2";

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
          VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
mysql_query($query);
```

It seems alrigth for me, but always returns "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'username'", that's because the username is an UNIQUE row, and there is a 0 value stored yet. The point is, I'm not trying to store any '0', do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance (Y)
And sorry for any mistakes, I'm brazilian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote your variables properly in query. Also check table structure and columns `data-type` and default values.  Your `username` column may have an integer type.

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
              VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."')";
```

Comment: I tried to concatenate too, but it keeps saying "duplicate entry" =/

Comment: what is default value of username column? Please paste table structure

Comment: OMG, now you told I just got what a fool thing I just did. The username column was INT, when it should be VARCHAR. Man, what a..!

Comment: Oh ya! This was only a cut of what was not working, the actual code has some useful purpose, like picking those variable with _POST method, validating and sanitizing them as well :-) Thank you guys!